# Can Windows Azure Mobile Services provide access to native mobile device functions?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a few project requirements for hybrid mobile apps. And in the quest of best thing I came across the Windows Mobile services. But my concern is whether it is providing any API for accessing native device function such as the camera or accelerometer along with Push Notifications.

I appreciate if any one can reply to my question as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

No.
Windows Azure Mobile Service is just for Client-Server communication, implementing data backend, full CRUD operations, and authentication.

Windows Azure Mobile Services is not cross-platform mobile application development solution. It is cross platform mobile development helper/sdk/add-in to help with `data` and `authentication`. For the rest, you have to chose the cross platform development environment from the wide range of such platforms: [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), [Icenium](http://www.icenium.com/), [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) to name a few.

Please note that **none** of the currently existing platforms (that I know) for cross-platform development currently provides the services that are available via Windows Azure Mobile Services. If you need to store data on a server, if you need to authenticate your mobile users - then you have to implement these features yourself, or use Azure Mobile Services in addition to the platform of your choice.

Comment: Although Icenium Everlive provide support of cloud backend for the apps, than how this Wiondows Azure Mobile Service makes a difference?
Thank you for your prompt reply.

Comment: This comment goes out of the scope of StackOverflow main subject and I will refrain from commenting further. Please read more on [Help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help) what questions may be asked here.